# Nested loop in table ruby on rails 6 view wrong order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, each

I have a category, which has work registrations. To show these in a table i use code below. However it gets executed in the wrong way. All categories are printed in the top of the table, while all work registrations are then posted below the list of categories. This is strange to me, as the work registrations loop is executed in the category loop. Any idea how to correct the code? I tried using group_by, however this gives the same result.

```
<table id="dataWorkRegistrations" class="table table-lightborder" data-class="WorkRegistration">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><%= t('work_registration.fields.code.label') %></th>
        <th><%= t('work_registration.fields.status.label') %></th>
        <th><%= t('work_registration.fields.name.label') %></th>
        <th><%= t('work_registration.fields.frequency.label') %></th>
        <th><%= t('work_registration.fields.amount.label') %></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @categories.each do |categorie| %>
        <tr class='bg-light'>
          <td><b><%= categorie.code %></b></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><b><%= categorie.name %></b></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <% categorie.work_registrations.each do |work_registration| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= work_registration.code %></td>
              <td><%= work_registration.status %></td>
              <td><%= work_registration.name %></td>
              <td><%= work_registration.frequency %></td>
              <td><%= work_registration.amount %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you check if same thing is happening after removing `class='bg-light'` ? Just wanted to confirm if is there any JS code doing this.

Comment: @Salil same thing stays after removing the class.

Comment: Strange! May be you can try creating a partial `_categorie.html.erb` and calling it in view like `<%= render partial: "categorie", collection: @categories, as: :categorie %>`

Comment: Are you sure all your categories have registrations?  To test I'd add a column to work registration table with the category code and see if your is data correct.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. As the table as an index for work_registrations. Datatables started to sort all, which caused the strange sorting. After disabling initial sorting on datatable, it worked instant.